# Polymer 2.0 building component

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have question about publishing/ building element in Polymer 2.0

I make polymer 2 application using bower. Then I coded my element. I can use it in this project when i call `<my-element></my-element>` in index.html.

What now I should do to "build" this element so in future I could import some JS? to project and using my component by adding `<my-element></my-element>` to my code?

I find this [tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/reusable-elements) for Polymer 1.x , but is this all what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what you need to do in order to publish your element to other Polymer programmers. Just to be clear, your element must be independent which means your file need to import all necessary polymer elements (and polymer itself). Then you need to have bower.json where are listed all needed dependecies.

You can take a look , for example, into paper-input element to see what did they use and how did they use it.

everything is described in tutorial you posted. By the way, the tutorial is for publishing it to everyone. If you don't want this, then you can just save your folder with element for future use in your pc (or some cloud) and later copy this folder with element into your project. Then just simply import main file by `<link rel="import" href="/path/to/element.html">` and that's it. IN HTML you can do `<my-element></my-element>`

Comment: Will using this "private" option not force me to use polymer serve every time I want to run a component? Is there any option to compile a component so that it behaves like a regular JS + httml? Something like build for  angular.

Comment: you don't need to build anything at all. just create file, write template needed to create element and reuse it as much as you wish. Building is used for production use. Once your project will be good enough you build it and place it on some hosting or server. Polymer serve just create localhost server. The same you can do with xampp or whatever else